# awk for generating Report from logfile

Tags: logging, awk, report, data-manipulation

I have a log that contains  strings like these:
1001031075825052016
1001041080225052016
1001030125825052016
1001031140325052016
1001040180025052016
1001030180125052016
1001031075926052016
1001041080226052016
1001030125926052016
1001031140126052016
1001030180026052016
1001030180026052016
where:
the first  6 character are the id, the 7th character is equal to 1 if people enter and 0 if exit,from character 8 to 11 is the hour and the last characther is the date.

Example:
1001030180015062016
means : user 100103 exit (0) at 18:00 on 15/06/2016

The file contain data of several user an can contain one or more month of data.
Is it possible with awk generate a report for each user and for each month (a csv or a excel file) like this?

```
USER:100103
Month: 05/2016
date        enter  exit   enter  exit   enter  exit enter exit
25/05/2016  07:58  12:58  14:03  18:01
26/05/2016  07:79  12:59  14:01  18:00         18:00
```

And is possible associate the name  of user to the id (example 100103 = mike)
to obtain something like this?(maybe I can generate a csv table with id; username)

```
USER:100103 - Mike
Month: 05/2016
date        enter  exit   enter  exit   enter  exit enter exit
25/05/2016  07:58  12:58  14:03  18:01
26/05/2016  07:79  12:59  14:01  18:00         18:00
```

Is it possible with awk or there is a simplest way?

Comment: I tried with excel pivot table without success, with awk i splitted the single field in different fild but I have not idea to how i can manipuate the data of different line and organize in single line o obtain the enter and the exit of the same day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NR==FNR { id2nm[$1] = $2; next }
match($0,/(.{6})(.)(.{4})(..)(..)(.*)/,a) {
    id=a[1]; act=a[2]; time=a[3]; day=a[4]; mth=a[5]; yr=a[6]

    sub(/../,"&:",time)

    if (act == 1) {
        ++numEvents[id][yr][mth][day]
    }

    eventNr = numEvents[id][yr][mth][day]
    events[id][yr][mth][day][eventNr][act] = time
}
END {
    print "ID", "Name", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Enter", "Exit", "..."
    for (id in events) {
        for (yr in events[id]) {
            for (mth in events[id][yr]) {
                for (day in events[id][yr][mth]) {
                    printf "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", id, OFS, id2nm[id], OFS, yr, OFS, mth, OFS, day
                    num = numEvents[id][yr][mth][day]
                    for (eventNr=1; eventNr<=num; eventNr++) {
                        enterTime = events[id][yr][mth][day][eventNr][1]
                        exitTime  = events[id][yr][mth][day][eventNr][0]
                        printf "%s%s%s%s", OFS, enterTime, OFS, exitTime
                    }
                    print ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk names log
ID,Name,Year,Month,Day,Enter,Exit,...
100103,Mike,2016,05,25,07:58,12:58,14:03,18:01
100103,Mike,2016,05,26,07:59,12:59,14:01,18:00
100104,Sue,2016,05,25,08:02,18:00
100104,Sue,2016,05,26,08:02,

$ awk -f tst.awk names log | column -s, -t
ID      Name  Year  Month  Day  Enter  Exit   ...
100103  Mike  2016  05     25   07:58  12:58  14:03  18:01
100103  Mike  2016  05     26   07:59  12:59  14:01  18:00
100104  Sue   2016  05     25   08:02  18:00
100104  Sue   2016  05     26   08:02
```

IMHO you should just produce CSV, not separate the ID and name into some kind of header, and you should use a YYYYMMDD year format so you can easily sort by date but you can massage the above to suit if you like. You'll need to add logic to handle an exit without an enter or anything else you care to identify/report/handle.

Comment: I used the script above.. works in 99% of situation but if one user in one day not have the enter but only the exit is not printed... is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Of course (I said that at in the last paragraph of my answer) but you should think about it and try to fix it yourself. All the awk syntax and language constructs you need are present in the question so I expect you can do it yourself but at least come up with the algorithm and pseudo-code. Feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Awk has one data structure, [arrays](https://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_12.html), which are basically dictionaries from strings to Awk values. Arrays are always one-dimensional, but you can "cheat" by writing commas in the index, which expand to the value of the variable SUBSEP (subscript separator), `"\034"` by default. So `arr["foo", "bar", "zonk"]` is the same as writing `arr["foo" SUBSEP "bar" SUBSEP "zonk"]`.

Since you can't scan arrays for all the keys of a particular subscript, in your application you will probably want to fill out a table of exit/entry dates plus additional tables that let you figure out which exits were by which person.

Assuming you have already split a line into fields and converted them to the appropriate values, this might look like:

```
/* assuming `user` is set to the six-digit ID code,
            `datetime` is set to whichever format you prefer,
            `direction` is one of "enter" or "exit" */
{
    i = ++nr_access_by_user[user]
    access_times[user, i] = datetime
    access_direction[user, i] = direction
}

END
{
    /* assuming you have already identified a specific value for `user`
       whose activity you want to log, and a function called `relevant`
       which determines if the access time comes from the day you want
       to log */
    for (i = 1; i <= nr_access_by_user[user]; i++)
    {
        if (relevant(access_times[user, i]))
        {
            print(access_times[user, i], access_direction[user, i])
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this gives you some direction for generating the specific output format you want.

The AWK Programming Language is an excellent book by the creators of the language that details tasks like this one. If you have the opportunity, I highly recommend reading it. **Edit:** Ed Morton points out that this book is severely outdated, and recommends Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. I learned from The AWK PL, so there might be several relevant features of modern Awk that I don't know about.

Comment: FYI GNU awk does have truly multi-dimensional arrays, see [Arrays-of-Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays-of-Arrays). Don't get The AWK Programming language as it's very out of date. Get Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as it describes all the modern POSIX constructs plus the gawk extensions.